# Differentiating between type int64 and type Long for pytorch neural network

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, casting

I am trying to train a PyTorch neural network, but upon forward pass the following error is being thrown: `RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float`

Despite casting the type of the input data to Long, this error still occurs.

Code for custom dataset class in which data type is converted into Long:

```
class MnistTrainDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.X = torch.tensor(df.iloc[:, 1:].values, dtype=torch.long).reshape((-1, 1, 28, 28))
        self.y = torch.tensor(df.iloc[:, 0].values, dtype=torch.long).reshape((-1, 1))
        print(self.X[0])
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.X[idx], self.y[idx]
```

The error was still raised when I included `dtype=torch.long`, so I also tried to change the whole tensor to Long via `type(torch.LongTensor)`, but this didn't fix the problem.

I printed the data type of the input data before the first step of the forward pass, and it gave this output: `torch.int64`, which, based on what I've read, is identical to the Long type. I am not sure why the error is raised if int64 and long are the same data type. Responses to other similar posts are mainly just manual casting in the ways I've tried before, but these haven't worked. What changes should I make to the MnistTrain class or forward pass to fix this?

Forward pass code:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.dtype)
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        print(x.dtype)
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2)
        print(x.dtype)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Full error:

```
2 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
      3     for X, y in train_iter:
----> 4         y_hat = net(X.type(torch.LongTensor))
      5         l = loss(y_hat.reshape(y.shape), y)
      7         optimiser.zero_grad()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/d2l/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1127 # this function, and just call forward.
   1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/Users/atikshgupta/Desktop/kaggle/digit_mnist/mnist_classifier.ipynb Cell 5' in Net.forward(self, x)
     10 def forward(self, x):
     11     print(x.dtype)
---> 12     x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
     13     print(x.dtype)
     14     x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/d2l/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1127 # this function, and just call forward.
   1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/d2l/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:457, in Conv2d.forward(self, input)
    456 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 457     return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/d2l/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:453, in Conv2d._conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    449 if self.padding_mode != 'zeros':
    450     return F.conv2d(F.pad(input, self._reversed_padding_repeated_twice, mode=self.padding_mode),
    451                     weight, bias, self.stride,
    452                     _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 453 return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    454                 self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float`
```

Comment: What is `self.conv1` defined as? Please show the `__init__` function of your model.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I have added the __init__ function to the code above

Comment: The default type for pytorch weights is float32 which is the same default type for tensors. Did you do anything to change the model dtype at some point or is it someone else's? Maybe you could try setting the dtype of the input to float32. Maybe it's float64 or something funky

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes for the data type conversion, it is asking for scaler type Long

```
data= data.type(torch.LongTensor)
```

Comment: I added this line for the input data but the error still occurs. It seems the data type stays at int64 even after adding this line.